# How do I prevent a jQuery Selector from including nested elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery so hopefully there is an easy answer to this.

I have html similar to:

```
<table id="dataTable">
    <tr> <!-- I want this row -->
        <td>...</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <table>
               <tr> <!-- I do not want this row -->
                   <td>...</td>
               </tr>
           </table>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

I am using jQuery similar to this:

```
$("#dataTable tr").length;
```

I would expect length to equal 2, but its returning 3 (includes the <tr> in the nested table.)  My question is: How do I prevent the 3rd <tr> from being selected?

I know that I could add an `ignorethisrow` class to the last row and exclude that from my results, but I'd prefer an option that allows me to control the *depth* that the select engine searches.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the syntax:

```
$("#dataTable > tr").length
```

mean "just tr's on the next level".